# Deleting an object

Tags: c++, object, memory-management

First, when you want to free the memory assigned to an object in C++, which one is preferred? Explicitly calling destructor or using delete?

```
Object* object = new Object(...);
...

delete object;
```

OR

```
object->~Object();
```

Second, does the delete operator call the destructor implicitly?

Comment: "A deconstructor is a philosopher that shows how the propositions of some text are undermined by the way the text makes its arguments."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`delete` implicitly calls the destructor, you don't need (more precisely: shouldn't) call it directly.

A destructor will never release the memory occupied by the object (It may reside on the stack, not on the heap, and the object has no way of knowing -- however, the destructor will delete any memory allocated by the object's components).

In order to free the memory of an object allocated on the heap, you must call `delete`.

When you write your own class, C++ will provide a *default destructor* to free the memory allocated by component objects (such as a `QString` that is a member of your class), but if you explicitly allocate memory (or other resources) in your constructor, be sure to provide a destructor that will explicitly free these resources.

Another general rule regarding your own classes: If you mark any methods `virtual`, your destructor should be `virtual`, as well (even if you rely on the default destructor), so that the correct destructor is called for any classes derived from yours.

Answer (score 7):

I prefer neither.

An explicit destructor call is needed very, very rarely, only when you are dissociating memory allocation from object lifetime. You might need it if implementing a custom container class.

An explicit `delete` is, potentially, a legitimate way to destroy an object dynamically created with a `new` expression but it should be unnecessary in most application code as it signals a place where potential mismatches between new and delete might occur and areas with potential exception safety issues.

Where an object lifetime is constrained to a block a local variable should normally be preferred as the memory allocation overhead is usually lower and the object will automatically be cleaned up correctly however the block is exited.

```
{
    // ...
    Object object( ... );

} // object destructor run, however this block is exited.
```

If there is some reason that this can't be need (e.g. the object has an excessive static size) or it's lifetime can't be matched to a particular scope, then usually some sort of smart pointer should be used to manage the objects lifetime. The most basic smart pointer which is available in standard C++ is `std::auto_ptr` which can be used for block scoped dynamically allocated objects but has 'surprising' behaviour on copy and assignment. Something like `tr1::shared_ptr` (or `boost::shared_ptr`) are common alternatives where shared ownership is needed.

```
{
    std::auto_ptr<Object> object(new Object(...));
    // ...
} // *object destructor run, however this block is exited.
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning hazards of manual lifetime management, although I would humbly suggest changing the example from auto_ptr to shared_ptr in order not to encourage anyone unfamiliar with its intricacies to use auto_ptr.

Answer (score 4):

delete is preferred.  Just calling the destructor does not free the memory allocated by the new.

Answer (score 4):

Use `delete`. It calls the objects *destructor* and then frees allocated memory.

*Also, it's not a deconstructor, but a destructor.*

Answer (score 4):

Normally you never want to explicitly call the destructor.  Just use `delete`.

Answer (score 4):

Invoking delete will invoke the destructor and then release the memory.

Invoke the destructor explicitly will only invoke the destructor, and not release the memory.

You should therefore almost always call delete: except when you want to invoke the destructor without releasing the memory, e.g. because you constructed the object using [placement new](http://www.google.com/#q=c%2B%2B+placement+new).

Answer (score 2):

You should never call the destructor yourself. **delete** will call it for you

Comment: If you do, you should ask yourself if your design isn't flawed

Comment: @Philippe Invoking the destructor directly is used to destroy objects which were instantiated using "placement new".

Comment: Then you'd better use a compiler which supports **placement delete**.

Comment: I think that placement delete isn't needed when you're using simple [placement new](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#placement-delete) into a preallocated buffer, whose lifetime you manage separately.

Comment: It's not needed, but it can be used for that purpose, and it's a cleaner solution than calling the destructor directly.

Comment: @Chris @Philippe: I'm just confused because there is no such thing as placement delete.

Comment: @Philippe: There is no placement delete expression unlike new which does have an optional placement form. You can define a placement form of `operator delete` but this does not destroy objects, it is called when it matches an `operator new` in a new expression and the object construction fails after the memory allocation succeeds to correctly deallocate the allocated raw memory. If a placement new expression succeeds then the correct way to destroy the object is with an explicit call to the destructor followed by a matching deallocation (if applicable).

Answer (score 2):

Something else to consider:

since `delete` calls the destructor internally, **it’s an error to do both**, i.e. calling the destructor and then delete. So the following code:

```
Foo* px = new Foo;
// …
px->~Foo();
delete px;
```

Will produce a nasty bug. Depending on the actions taken in the actual destructor, this may go unnoticed for quite some time, since the compiler actually allows this code. This may lead to subtle, hard to discover bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You should use delete

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html

Answer (score 0):

When you are using dynamic memory allocation to create the object at that time you can use the delete operator to destroy/delete the object but when you are not using DMA at that time trying to delete an object using delete operator throws error. One way to handle this situation is, writing your own destructor explicitly and calling the destructor using the object to destroy it.